# Automapper profile to map object with nested list to destination list

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Hard to convey the question in the title. Trying to determine the best way to write an automapper profile to map between two objects into lists but the number of items in the destination list will be equal to the number of items in an internal list on the source object. Please find an example of what I'm after:

```cs
public class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<FooBar> FooBar { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map `Source -> List<Destination>` where the number of items in `Destination` equals the number of `FooBar` in `Source` but they also each have an `Id` and `Description` from the `Source`.

Comment: If there is only one `Source` does that mean that each `FooBar` has the same `Id` and `Description`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.CreateMap<Source, List<Destination>>()
                    .ConvertUsing(source => source.FooBar.Select(fb => new Destination
                    {
                        Foo = fb.Foo,
                        Bar = fb.Bar,
                        Description = source.Description,
                        Id = source.Id
                    }).ToList()
                )
```

Obviously, use it like this

```
var destination = mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(Source);
```

Comment: Yep, that did it thanks so much!